# Как вызвать форму в C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Привет всем.

Написал фтп, создал форму, кнопки сделал, по кнопкам прописал функции. Сначала было без main, добавил main, теперь не знаю, как с мэина вызвать форму.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using FTP_lib;

namespace Project1 {

    static void Main() {
    }

    public partial class Form1: Form {
        ftp_Manager newFtpManager = new ftp_Manager();

        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void username_txtb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        }

        private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            newFtpManager.ftp_Username = username_txtb.Text;
            newFtpManager.ftp_Password = password_txtb.Text;
        }

        private void getContent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            newFtpManager.getContent("ftp://youdomain.com");
        }

        private void upload_file_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            newFtpManager.UploadFile("ftp://yourdomain.com/filedestination", "C:\\myfile.exe");
        }

        private void donwload_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            newFtpManager.DownloadFile("ftp://ftp.mama.tomsk.ru/festival/", "C:\\Download");
        }

        private void delete_file_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            newFtpManager.DeleteFile("ftp://yourdomain.com/file.exe");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создаете экземпляр этой формы.

```
Form1 example = new Form1();
example.Show();
```

**Добавлено из комментария.**

Main старайтесь как можно меньше менять. Когда надо вызвать нужную форму, используйте метод AddWindow:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void AddWindow()
    {
        Form2 examp = new Form2();
        examp.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вот так? Ничего не происходит...

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Form1 example = new Form1(); 
            example.Show();
        }
      

        ftp_Manager newFtpManager = new ftp_Manager();
        public Form1()

Comment: Перенесено в ответ.

Comment: public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        static void Main()
        {
            AddWindow();
        }

Comment: Ругается Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Project1.Form1.AddWindow()' C:\Users\Семен\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\Project1\Form1.cs 19 13 Project1

Comment: а все работает, при создании надо было указать windows form, а я указал как консольное приложение

Comment: http://turbobit.net/t97uyvx50szc.html
Посмотри пример

Answer (score 2):

в формах static void Main() не нужен.

а в файле (по умолчанию) program.cs *должны быть* строчки

static void Main()

```
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new <Название вашей формы>());
    }
```

Comment: спасибо, но уже разобрался)